# C# not downloading the actual file?

Tags: c#, download

I'm trying to download a simple .txt file, using the following code:

```
 WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
 webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(Completed);
 webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(ProgressChanged);
 webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("http://www.webscripts.atw.hu/a.txt"), @"c:\tmp\TEST01.txt");
```

For some reason the downloaded file contains the source code of the webpage, and no content of the text file. I have no idea why this happens. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This links to a page with an iframe, which has the text file inside. Try this url: `http://users.atw.hu/webscripts/a.txt`

You can go to the original page and check page source.